# click event on an ellipse in p5.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to make a little game with p5js while learning more about javascript,
so I want to detect click events when I click on these moving circles but I feel like I'm kind of stuck here.
meanwhile this is my code:
ps: sorry for the noob question

````
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  // let x = random(width);

  let x = map(noise(xoff), 0, 1, 0, width);

  xoff += 0.01;
   this.r= 50;
    let bubble= ellipse(x, 100, r*2);
   let bubble2= ellipse(x, 200, r*2);
    let bubble3= ellipse(x, 300, r*2);
    



}
  

  function clicked(){
     
 let d = dist (mouseX, mouseY, x, 200);
    if (d<this.r){
 console.log('clicked on buubble');
    }

  }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try first with a single bubble. Eventually there should be a bubble class to create multiple instances of bubbles.

Utilze the mousePressed function to detect clicks (https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed).

Here an example with one bubble:

```
let xoff = 1;
let r = 50;
let bubbleX;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  bubbleX = map(noise(xoff), 0, 1, 0, width);
  xoff += 0.01;
  ellipse(bubbleX, 200, r * 2);
}


function mousePressed() {
  let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, bubbleX, 200);
  if (d < r) {
    console.log('clicked on bubble');
  }
}
```

Hope that helps to progress into the right direction.

Comment: thx a lot :D, ur code made more sense to me
that was quite helpful

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to accept the answer to close this topic.